# How can I measure performance characteristics under rayleigh channel of a manet built-in model in omnet++ 6.0?

Tags: c#, communication, omnet++, inet

I have to measure the performance characteristics of any built in manet network that could be present in omnet++ 6 under fading channels.
Also i have to find the bit error rate as well as Signal to Noise Ratio of the network.

Comment: I would start by reading the Wki article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network.  You have a graph.  Normally when you transverse a graph there is a distance between adjacent node.  In this case the distance also have a SNR.  So transverse the graph using Dijkstra and calculate the BER between all points.